# Akka Streams: How to convert a Future[Seq[T]] to Source[T, NotUsed]

Tags: akka, akka-stream

I've a method: `def sightings(from: YearMonth): Future[Seq[Sighting]]`

And another: `def sightings(from: YearMonth, to: YearMonth): Source[Sighting, NotUsed]`

I'd like to call the first one for each `YearMonth` starting with `from` and ending at `to`, and merge/concat the results. I can't seem to find a suitable method on `Source` to do that. What I've now is the following:

```
val months = from.until(to, ChronoUnit.MONTHS) + 1
Source.fromIterator(() => Iterator.range(0, months.toInt))
    .map(from.plusMonths(_))
    .mapAsyncUnordered(1)(sightings)
```

This produces a `Source[Int, NotUsed]`, not a `Source[Sighting, NotUsed]` like I'm looking for.

**Edit**:
I ended up with the following:

```
trait Client {
  def sightings(yearMonth: YearMonth): Source[(HttpResponse, YearMonth), NotUsed]
}

trait HttpClient extends Client {
  implicit def system: ActorSystem

  private val yearMonthFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMM")

  override def sightings(yearMonth: YearMonth): Source[(HttpResponse, YearMonth), NotUsed] = {
    Source.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create() { implicit b: GraphDSL.Builder[NotUsed] =>
      import GraphDSL.Implicits._

      // prepare graph elements
      val uri = "whatever.html"
      val src = Source.single(RequestBuilding.Get(uri))
      lazy val conn = Http().outgoingConnection("www.doesnotexist.com")
        .map((_, yearMonth))

      val flow = b.add(conn)

      // connect the graph
      src ~> flow

      // expose port
      SourceShape(flow.out)
    })
  }
}

trait Crawler {
  self: Client =>

  implicit def executionContext: ExecutionContext

  implicit def materializer: Materializer

  final def sightings(from: YearMonth, to: YearMonth): Source[Sighting, NotUsed] = {
    val months = from.until(to, ChronoUnit.MONTHS) + 1

    Source.fromIterator(() => Iterator.range(0, months.toInt))
      .map(x => from.plusMonths(x.toLong))
      .flatMapConcat(self.sightings)
      .mapAsyncUnordered(1)(t => {
        val (response, yearMonth) = (t._1, t._2)
        val body = Unmarshal(response.entity).to[String]
        val status = response.status

        responseMapper(body, yearMonth)(status)
      })
      .mapConcat(_.to[collection.immutable.Seq])
  }

  import scala.collection.JavaConversions._

  private def responseMapper(body: Future[String], yearMonth: YearMonth):
  PartialFunction[StatusCode, Future[Seq[Sighting]]] = {...}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on the type signature of the first `sightings` function (`def sightings(from: YearMonth): Future[Seq[Sighting]]`) it sounds like you want a function with this type:

```
def fToS[A, B](f: A => Future[Seq[T]]): Flow[A, B, NotUsed]
```

You could then do this:

```
val yearMonths: Source[YearMonth, NotUsed] = ??? // whatever you want
val toSightings: Flow[YearMonth, Sighting, NotUsed] = fToS(sightings)
val source: Source[Sighting, NotUsed] = yearMonths.via(toSightings)
```

`fToS` would look something like this:

```
def fToS[A, B](f: A => Future[Seq[T]]): Flow[A, B, NotUsed] =
  Flow[A].mapAsync(1)(f).mapConcat(identity)
```

That should work.

Comment: You could also use `Source.fromFuture(fut).mapConcat(identity)`.